# Running commands in three command prompts automatically?

Tags: windows

How can I run a given set of commands an arbitrary number of times? I mean - I have a server which hosts a simple console game which is ran using one command and two client programs which are to compete over the server (each started with one command too). How can I run these three commands automatically some number of times automatically rather than by opening three separate command prompt windows and repeating the last command in each manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a batch file (start.bat)
and inside write

```
start command1.exe
start command2.exe
start command3.exe
```

this will open 3 console windows and execute corresponding command at the same time

Comment: That's great, completely forgot about the good old .bats :) Thank you a lot.